# Official docs use map method without return but doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React.js official docs use the map method without return and it works in CodePen.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li>{number}</li>
);
```

I need to use return otherwise it doesn't work for me. I have a copy of React.js on my Windows local machine made using create-react-app module. Node.js version 6.9.4

```
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>{
    return <li>{number}</li>
  }
);
```

[Offical docs rendering multiple components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `it doesn't work for me.` ? Does it not render? Do you get an console error?

Comment: It renders fine. My question is which way is correct in React.js? Do I have to do something to make it work without return? Or why can they use without return but I have to?

Comment: There is nothing different about the map prototype function when dealing with arrays in React. Here is a codepen mapping the array without using a return https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxgKEr

Comment: Can you show us when you get when you try to map the array without a return? "it doesn't work for me" isn't helpful in diagnosing your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is a React issue. It is just JavaScript. In ES6/ES2015 if you use an arrow function (within a `.map` call or anywhere else), you can eliminate both the curly braces and `return` keyword if all you are doing is returning a value determined by an expression. Thus the following two are equivalent:

```
const result1 = array.map((element) => {return modify(element);});
const result2 = array.map((element) =>         modify(element)  );
```

Comment: Of course that's the problem! I forgot about that. Thanks. I edited my answer to show that I was using it with curly braces.